# Pytezos: transfer endpoint

Tags: python, pytezos

I get an unexpected arguments error while trying to make a transfer endpoint call.

```
my_contract.transfer([{
"transfer_item":
    {
      "from_": "tz1...",
      "txs": [{
            "txs_item": 
                {
                    "to_": "tz1...",
                    "token_id": 0,
                    "amount": 5
                }
        
        }]
    }
}])
```

The structure should look like this:

```
$transfer_item:
    {
      "from_": address,
      "txs": [ $txs_item, … ]
    }

$txs_item:
        {
          "to_": address,
          "token_id": nat,
          "amount": nat
        }
```

I'm unsure if I nested it wrong or where I made the mistake.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're trying to transfer an FA2 token, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct format of the argument to transfer an FA2 token:

```
my_contract.transfer([{
    "from_": "tz1...",
    "txs": [{
        "to_": "tz1...",
        "token_id": 0,
        "amount": 5
    }]
}])
```

So, you don't need to pass the names `transfer_item` and `txs_item`.

Comment: nice thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome :)